# Java getting substring from square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get a substring from square brackets in a string, I tried multiple regexes but nothing works.

I tried multiple regexes and code from multiple stackoverflow posts but nothing works.

```
String mydata = "some string with [the data i want] inside";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(.*?)]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    output = output.replace("%item%", matcher.group(1));
}
```

It should return "the data i want" but instead it says that no pattern was found.

Comment: `[` must be escaped to match a literal `[` char. See https://ideone.com/8FYZbu

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/IRS1Ef/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew a closing bracket is automatically escaped if there is no opening bracket before?

Comment: @Cid There is no need to escape `]` as the regex engine knows if it closes the character class or not. Inside a character class in Java regexes though, both `[` and `]` must be escaped.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nice, something new I've learnt. RegEx engines are really smart :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `[]` characters so they are seen as literal square brackets.

Using this as your regex should work: `\\[(.*?)\\]`

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked